# UIImageView not showing images on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiimageview

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application and have to change the LaunchScreen.storyboard file. 
I added an ImageViewer and selected an image but it doesn't load in the storyboard.

The image property dropdown keeps empty.

have anyone ever faced a problem like that?

Comment: Where is the image located?

Comment: you can post the code of the buggy storyboard here for others to check

Comment: the image is located in resources folder @Jason.

Comment: there's no code, i'm editing the storyboard only in visual mode @NickKovalsky

Comment: LaunchScreen.storyboard can be viewed as code and pasted here

Comment: thanks @NickKovalsky, I posted below

Answer (score 0):

i have the same Problem since i updated VS to the newest Version (15.8.1)
It creates the image in the resources Folder. My workaround for now is to set up the whole image and after that close the editor and manually add image="file.png" to the imageView's attributes.
Super stupid but it works...

Comment: how do you add the image manually? I've tried to write in property window but nothing happens

Comment: @GabrielPellegrini if the image is already in the assets folder just open the storyboard via a text or xml editor (Open with...) and insert
**image="yourfile.png"**
into the properties of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The code follows below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14113" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="280">
        <dependencies>
            <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
            <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
        </dependencies>
        <scenes>
            <!--View Controller-->
            <scene sceneID="279">
                <objects>
                    <viewController id="280" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                        <layoutGuides>
                            <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="277"/>
                            <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="278"/>
                        </layoutGuides>
                        <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="281">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="736"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" id="284" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" fixedFrame="YES">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="87" y="304" width="240" height="128"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                </imageView>
                            </subviews>
                        </view>
                    </viewController>
                    <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="282" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
                </objects>
                <point key="canvasLocation" x="271" y="359"/>
            </scene>
        </scenes>
        <color key="tintColor" colorSpace="calibratedWhite" white="1" alpha="1"/>
    </document>
```

Comment: Dunno why its bugging but you can manually insert after </scenes> and before </document> the following  <resources>
        <image name="yourimage.png" width="676" height="182"/>
    </resources>

Comment: needless to say change image size in this text